# schedule backup job runs up to 9 hrs without errors

Tags: scheduled-task, sql-server-2012, database-backup

I'm very new to administration job...

I have `SQL server 2012`, on that my senior scheduled a job for schedule backup. But, recently I noticed, after `8-May-2018`(up to `26-May-2018`) the backup files are missing. Then I realize that, the schedule job  hadn't ran after that.
Now I run the same job, which up to 9 hours without neither error nor success.

[image: List of servers and job running window]

How to I get normal schedule backup of all DBs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how much data you are dealing with and the speed of your backup target, 9 hours may be entirely fine.  Without knowing more details, I will make the following recommendations.

1. Download and run Brent Ozar's [Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) health-check script. Issues that it identifies are usually accompanied by a link to a blog post that explains the detected problem and its fix.  Try to correct any problems with severity 150 or less.
2. Download [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/). These include integrity checks, index optimizations, and backups that are far more efficient than the stock jobs that come with SQL Server.
3. Because your databases haven't backed up for a while, figure out how long your backups would take if the next one was a complete backup.  This should set your expectation for how long is reasonable for the backup job to run.  For example:  if you have 2 TB of database to back up, and your storage target is a single external hard drive with a write speed of 50 MB / sec, your backup is going to take a minimum of 11 hours.

Comment: Rob, `9 hours may be entirely fine` is good point. I accepted... But I've one doubt. I'll ask, if job runs successfully.

Comment: Rob.. I asked my new question. Please [follow this](https://serverfault.com/questions/914123/transaction-backup-job-is-run-event-full-and-different-job-cant-run)

Comment: I'll go there now.

Answer (score 0):

Now the job has completed without error. Because, my colleague change the Job's `start Date` as current date(2/7/2018). So, I've running Job. Where as backup file from `2/7/2018` to today`9/7/2018` files are available.
And before `2 July 2018` to `8 May 2018` date files are missing. Any way I will manage available files....!!

Thanks to all.. _/\_

Regards,

TamilPugal